# Simple questions: CSS page layout

Tags: html, css, layout

Bear with me, I will now post a dumb question. Being an amateur at web-design, I don't fully comprehend CSS. Specifically, how to arrange objects in the horizontal plane.

Right now, the dashed <'p>' box is below the empty <'div>' box. I want to put them next to each other, horizontally. How to go about it?

```
<html><head><style>
#div1
{width:400px; height:75px;border:4px solid;}
</style></head><body>

<div id="div1"></div>

<p style="border-style:dashed;border-width:2px;height:30px;width:396px;text-align:center;">Move me</p>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't feel bad that you haven't grasped CSS layout yet – it has been a long time coming in terms of standards support, so most methods today use slightly hacky methods to acheive it, and it's not always self-evident how they work or why.

Blocks by default stack vertically, so you want to change the flow to run horizontally for a specific part.

The proper "modern CSS way" would be to use flexbox, which is specifically a layout tool for these types of situations (and more). The caveat is browser support – IE10 and above, but otherwise most every browser supports it.

To lay something out horizontally with flexbox, you'd tell the parent to become a horizontally oriented container. In your case, it might therefore be a good idea to wrap the two elements in another element:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <p>Move me</p>
</div>
```

You then tell the wrapper to become a "flex container", where the default mode is to flow boxes horizontally rather than vertically:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

There have historically been a couple of experimental flexbox implementations with different syntax, so that's something to be aware of too (see example later).
The next step would be to size the boxes, if you want them to be sized other than according to content – that would be the next step in learning about flexbox. :-)
The first thing you will need to know is that they will still react to the `width` property in this situation, and otherwise stretch to become equally tall.

If you want wider browser support, you can combine flexbox with other methods that aren't as fit for this exact purpose but still work – floats or inline block comes to mind. The nice thing about flexbox is that it ignores the `display` mode and `float` properties of its children. This means that we can combine old and new techniques.

- Floats are originally intended to position images or other figures to the right or left in blocks of text, for example, but can be used to create whole layouts with a bit of work. They have some complex behaviors that take a while to grasp. For example, since floats stick out of their container vertically by default, you usually need to add something that makes the wrapper enclose the floats – the easiest way is probably to apply `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper.
- Inline blocks are basically to allow block level elements in the flow of text, but since text flows horizontally (in English, at least) you can co-opt them to create full horizontal layouts as well. The downside is that any whitespace (including linebreaks) in the HTML source will create whitespace between the horizontal items.

If you go the float route, the example code could look something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  /* various flexbox syntaxes, old */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* modern flexbox syntax */
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; /* contain floats */
}

.wrapper p,
#div1 {
  float: left; /* will be ignored by modern browsers */
}
```

Comment: Det var så lite så, @HungryHippo. :-)
Markera gärna svaret som accepterat om du tycker det besvarar din fråga.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) (inline, or inline-block)

> An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as
>   much width as necessary.

**CSS**

```
#div1, p{
display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/g2jw1zp2/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should set `display` to `inline-block` for them. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zybp5qy3/).

Also you may set them `vertical-align: top` (look at fiddle again) and they'll be aligned to top.

Right now `<p>` a little bit below `<div>`. Set `margin` for `p` to `0` for change it.

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left for the first div

{width:400px; float:left; height:75px;border:4px solid;}

Answer (score 0):

The way I personally would do this is to add a wrapper to both of these elements and align them textually with text-align

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1"></div>

    <p style="border-style:dashed;border-width:2px;height:30px;width:396px;text-    align:center;">Move me</p>
</div>
```

and then add some CSS to that wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```